# While using source control, how can I have different permissions for groups of users for different parts of the source code?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, git-submodules

I have a problem about applying source control. I tried lots of things but I cannot figure it out. While using source control, I want to be able to have different permissions for groups of users for different parts of the source code.

We used to have one big repository containing the entire (Visual Studio) solution and all projects. But this time we need to be able to manage the permissions for different parts of the source code (per projects). This is important for protecting some parts of the intellectual property.

*To provide a little illustration of the context:*

- We develop code (mostly C# and C++) in Visual Studio (VS). We use `Azure-DevOps` in combination with `git` repositories.
- I have a (VS) solution that consists of many (20+) projects (project1, project2, ...).
- Most of these projects do not really run on their own (or it doesn't make sense to do it).
- You could consider these project e.g. libraries, (optional) modules/plugins.
- Each project requires different specific domain knowledge to develop.
- For certain tests, we need to have all the code in one big solution available so we can debug and set break points e.g.

*What did I try:*

Lots of things, but the closest to a working solution was:

- I created a separate repositories for each project. Then I can indeed manage the permissions per user very well.
- I created a repository for the solution, let's call this repository the `CombinedRepo`.
- Added the projects as `git-submodules` to `CombinedRepo`.

This set-up works when pulling the `CombinedRepo` incl. the submodules using VS. I can test, debug and make changed etc.

*However, I have the following issues with this set-up:*

- When we work in `CombinedRepo` and changed code of one of the submodules, and want to commit these changes, we get this error: `fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output.` (This is when using VS to commit).
- The other way around does also not work: If changes have been made in a submodule's own repo, I cannot pull these changes to our `CombinedRepo` (when using VS).

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I kind of changed my approach: instead of using Git, I'm now using TFSC which allows to easily set folder/file permissions. For the rest TFSC seems to fulfill all requirements instead. We have a working solution using TFSC.
However, I think your answer/instruction look very good and if it indeed works it is valuable knowledge. I have not tested it (yet) but I will probably test it some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio sees changes made in submodule folders, but fails to commit them.

To workaround it, go to Team Explorer - Manage Connections - Local Git Repositories - Add, browse to submodule folder and confirm with Add. Double click on the local repository created to open it.

Now You can commit changes and push them to the remote origin like You would do just in original submodule repository.

Than open again Your local repository containing the submodule folder, go to changes and commit them to include changed submodule state in main module.

Here are some feature request links, you could follow them to get the latest news.

- [Full Git submodule support](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351549/full-git-submodule-support.html)
- [Allow multiple Git repositories to be active at once](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351156/allow-multiple-git-repositories-to-be-active-at-on.html)

In addition, If you only want to restrict users or team members from submitting code, we could set [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) and disable the branch permission [Bypass policies when pushing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops#permissions-in-azure-devops-server-2019-through-azure-devops-services). Then all users need to create pull request to push the commit, and you could check the commit and approve the Pull Request.

**Update**

> I want to be able to have different permissions for groups of users for different parts of the source code.

Thanks for Stefan sharing.

If we are using TFVC repo, we could configure the folder/file permission for groups of users. Check the pic below.

[image]

Comment: This answer looks very good! I have not tested it because I have found another working solution for now (to use TFSC in stead of Git). However, once I tested this, and if it indeed works, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, I shared your solution in the answer, you could also share your answer here and mark it as the answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: I was planning to add it as an answer but I hadn't taken the time yet. I also wanted to test your solution and mark that as accepted answer if that also worked.
But now you have both solutions in your answer. I marked it as the accepted answer Tanks for taking the time to help me (and others in the future)!

Comment: I want to add. A disadvantage of migrating from Git to TFSC repo was that I now lost the history (at least, it remains in the Git repo). It seems only possible to migrate the history when going from TFSC to Git and not the other way around. The options that exists today to migrate Git to TFSC have been depreciated or did only work the other way around. This is something to take into account if someone plans to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you have made a change in a submodule, you must switch to that submodule in order to successfully commit the change.

(This information is taken from https://jonasr.app/2020/04/vs-git-subm/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, and yes we found that blog also :). We have over 20 submodule. The problem with switching to each submodule, is that committing can become very time consuming. I actually hope there is a more proper way to achieve what we want. It seems like quite a standard problem for companies working with larger teams.